# Print Multiple Images using Processstartinfo.verb="print" command

Tags: vb.net, printing

i want to print all the images in a folder by using Processstartinfo.verb="print" command

i have the code to print single image like this

```
dim psinfo as new processstartinfo
psinfo.verb="print"
psinfo.createnowindow=false
psinfo.filename="d:/imgfolder/0001.jpg"
process.start(psinfo)
```

but i want to print more images at a time by using this command.
in Folder if i select all images(Ctrl+A) and then RightClick and then print. then this is working fine and printing all images. in the same way i want to print images using vb.net
if Anyone know how to do this please reply....

Answer (score 0):

```
    Dim psinfo As New ProcessStartInfo
    Dim files() As String
    Dim strfile As String
    If Directory.GetFiles("d:/imgfolder", "*.jpg").Any() Then
        files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("d:/imgfolder", "*.jpg")
        psinfo.Verb = "print"
        psinfo.createnewwindow = False
        For Each file As String In files
            strfile = file
            psinfo.FileName = strfile
            Process.srart(psinfo)
        Next
    End If
```

This will loop through all `images(*.jpg)` files in your folder `d:/imgfolder`

Comment: hi , thanks for your reply.i tried this code . then i got the error"The system cannot find the file specified". then i changed code as "psinfo.FileName = file.FullName" in For each loop. But Here i am able to get Only LastFile to the preview.....But i required to show all the Files.... please check once.....

Comment: what you getting in `file.Name` ?

Comment: "The system cannot find the file specified"

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your update. i tried this code.i got 5 different printwindows for 5 images.but i want only one window with 5 images one by 1 by showing image 1 of 5, 2 of 5 like that..please see..(in Folder if we Select ALl images(CTRL+A)and print all images will bind to one print window like that i have to show ...) please check this....